# Converting personal geodatabase feature class to coverage using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, vba, arcinfo-workstation

how to convert  personal geodatabase fatureclass to coverage using arcobjects with vba

pls provide me any documentation or samples.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have an ArcInfo license (checked out). Then call the [ESRI.ArcGIS.ConversionTools.FeatureclassToCoverage](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/gp_toolref/conversion_tools/feature_class_to_coverage_conversion_.htm) geoprocessing function

[These sample](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/net/ViewCodePages/43d8cc77-5193-4ca8-9878-6027782e2bbbexecutetoolcopyfeatures.cs.htm)s should give you an idea on how to call it from .NET - it should be doable from any of the other languages that support COM.

Answer (score 0):

I found this forum where another user discusses and presents some vba code for doing what you are trying to do: http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=982&t=51315